# What's the best way to allow for keyboard navigation on a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, accessibility

First I don't have any code to share, but more of a general help question. I have built a custom WordPress site and I want to make the header / footer nav elements keyboard focusable and be able to open using the keyboard. I want to know if:

1. There is anything I can do with the HTML Markup (using Tabindex, for example) or
2. Do I need to custom-write this functionality with JavaScript?

[Here's my live site for a Demo, feel free to inspect source code](https://www.fralinpickups.com/)

**The Main Problem** is that by loading the page and tabbing through the elements, the browser skips the header and footer, and jumps further down the page. This is common on all pages.

**Functionality expected:** I want the user to tab to the first account / search links, followed by the eCommerce links, followed by the navigation links. I'm using Bootstrap 4.6.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the main problem on your page. Tab key correctly focusses the main navigation links. So the functionality expected is already there, except for that you cannot open the submenus by means of keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab order on your page seems correct. What is not working is expanding the submenus correctly.

From the [Bootstrap documentation on navbar dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#navbarNavDropdown), this would be the correct markup:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
```

For better accessibility, `role="button"` and `aria-expanded` need to be added and updated by means of JavaScript. The JS Dropdown-plugin will pick up `data-toggle="dropdown"` and handle all this.

Currently on the linked page, the expanding logic is added in CSS for :hover only, which is not accessible to touchscreen our keyboard users.

It’s a quite common issue with such dropdown navigation menus, that touchscreen and keyboard users are left out because the design decision was to open the submenu *and* have the parent item a clickable link at the same time.

You’ll need to get rid of that. A common workaround is to add a visually different *Overview* link at the top of each submenu.

### Mark the current page in a menu

You also have the usability-issue that the current page is not visually marked, nor for assistive technology.

Bootstrap 4 uses the `active` class for the `menu-item` to do so, and recommends adding a hidden `(current)` text in the link.

But you can also combine this with the Bootstrap 5 way of adding the `aria-current="page"` to the link:

```html
<li class="nav-item active"><a aria-current="page" href="https://www.fralinpickups.com/blog/" class="nav-link">The Workbench</a>
```

Comment: Andy thank you for taking the time to look into this issue and provide such a detailed answer. I'll be digging into this on my next project. Thanks again, and have a great day.

Comment: The example doesn't work. It is incorrect HTML. After adding closing tags, it still doesn't work in Bootstrap 5.

Comment: This conversation concerns Bootstrap 4.6. What is the issue you encountered?